# Extracting attachments from emails sent by Outlook In Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook, mime-types, email-attachments

I am using AWS SES to receive emails and I want to extract the attachments and save them into S3. I am saving the Raw email in S3 and then processing it in Lambda with JS. This work with emails received that were sent from Gmail, but not outlook. The Outlook attachments are Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat". Is there any way to cover this back to the original attached file or another way to get the attachment?

Thanks.

Not sure what to try. Never seen Content-Type: application/ms-tnef.

Answer (score 0):

Transport Neutral Encapsulation Format or TNEF is a proprietary email attachment format used by Microsoft Outlook and Microsoft Exchange Server. An attached file with TNEF encoding is most often named winmail.dat or win.dat, and has a MIME type of Application/MS-TNEF. TNEF encoding is performed when the message is created, and the software used to send the message determines whether or not to encode the attachments with TNEF. Outlook and Exchange offer a message formatting option called Rich Text (or RTF - Rich Text Format). When a message is formatted as Rich Text, the attachments will be formatted with TNEF, so the terms are sometimes used synonymously. RTF refers to the message format and TNEF refers to the attachment format. There are several different places where this formatting can be selected and controlled.

You can try using libraries like [MimeKit](http://www.mimekit.net/).

Comment: Hi, I have used MailParser, to help sort through the raw email. I will try MineKit.